# New Network Device "Incoming Connections"

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet-connection

[image: Screenshot of Device]
[image: Properties of Device]

Since today I suddenly have this device in my network list. Yesterday, I unplugged my wireless stick and connected my computer via cable to my Speedport Router.

Does anyone know where this device comes from, why it is there, what it does and how I can get rid of it?

Maybe it is noteworthy that my phone connection is IP based, but as I said, this never turned up before and I didn't change anything within Windows or my Router that would make this appear.

Comment: Does this help you any further? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753616%28v=ws.10%29.aspx and http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/allowing_access.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: What Speedport router exactly? Does it have any fancy options?

Comment: @JanDoggen http://www.telekom.de/privatkunden/geraete-und-zubehoer/wlan-und-router/speedport-w-724v This one. Yeah it has a lot of options. Hold on, I update my post a bit. edit: also, my network icon in Windows is showing the red cross, which would indicate no network cable is plugged in, but everything works fine.